# Why can this class and its member be directly referenced?

Tags: c#, object, properties, static, instantiation

I came across this code:

```
pc = new PendingCommands(pause, wait);
PendingCommands.ProcessCommands = true;
```

I wonder two things:

> 1) Did the coder mean to write: pc.ProcessCommands = true?
>
> 2) Why is that second line even allowed? PendingCommands is not marked static...

If I right-click "pc" and select "Go to Definition" or "Go To Declaration" it takes me here (in the same class/file):

```
public static PendingCommands pc = null;
```

If I right-click "PendingCommands" (from either spot) and select "Go to Definition" or "Go To Declaration" it takes me here (in a separate class/file):

```
public class PendingCommands : IDisposable
```

The "ProcessCommands" member is defined within the "PendingCommands" class this way:

```
public volatile static bool ProcessCommands = true;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `Did the coder mean to write: pc.ProcessCommands = true?` No, he didn't. `PendingCommands is not marked static` Yes, but `ProcessCommands` is declared static and belongs to class, not to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
public volatile static bool ProcessCommands = true;
```

Notice how `ProcessCommands` is static. That means it's related to the type (`PendingCommands`), not an instance of the type.

It's almost certainly not a good design (public fields rarely are, static mutable fields rarely are, volatile fields rarely are) but it explains why it's fine to write `PendingCommands.ProcessCommands = true;`

It's hard to know whether it was really *meant* to be static - whether it's just a bug, or whether it was designed that way without any more information, unfortunately. (I'd be nervous about using this class just on the basis of that field, but...)

Note that you mention "`PendingCommands` is not marked static" - it's not the *class* which needs to be static. A static class is just one which only has static members, and can't be instantiated (or used as a variable type etc). It's the *member you're accessing* which is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `static` fields of any classes via the class name even if the class itself is not `static`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is this a mistake? Did the coder mean to write: `pc.ProcessCommands = true`?

Possibly - no way to know without full documentation on `PendingCommands`.

> 2) Why is that second line even allowed? PendingCommands is not marked static...

The `PendingCommands` class may not be marked as `static`, but the `ProcessCommands` property is.

Comment: Documentation?!? Ha! FULL documentation?!? ROTFLMAO.

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessCommands` is accessible because it is `static`.   Remove the `static` keyword, and it will only be accessible in relation to an instance of the class.  i.e. `pc`.

`PendingCommands.ProcessCommands = true` may be a mistake unless `PendingCommands` is intended to be used as a singleton.  That is, there is only intended to be one instance of the class, so the static method `ProcessCommands` will process all of the "commands" of its only instance.